# How can i split a column delimiter with spaces?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a csv delimited with spaces that can change to 9-10-11, it s there a way for split the column in two with Azure data factory?

Examples:

This is my CSV

[image]

I try using dataflows:

[image]

but when I execute the dataflow, it throw me this error:

[image]

PD: the csv has 4.000.000 rows

Solve the problem using azure data factory, the csv needs to finish in my DW

Answer (score 0):

- I have the following data in my sample csv file with either 9, 10 or 11 spaces in between the value.

[image]

- Now, after reading the column, use `derived column` transformation to split the required column using 9 spaces (minimum number of spaces).

```
req1 : split(col1,'         ')[1]
req2 : split(col1,'         ')[2]
```

- This will split the data into an array of 2 elements, where 1st index will have no spaces in its value and the 2nd index element has trailing spaces.

[image]

- Now apply `ltrim` on the req2 column. Check the length of this column before and after the transformation to confirm that we are eliminating the trailing spaces.

```
req2 : ltrim(req2)
```

[image]

- After doing this, you can check the length of the `req2` and it would be 1.

[image]

- Now, select only the required columns and then write it to required sink.

Comment: i have do it with dataflows and it s give the right output but in dataflow when i put the sink (it s a datawarehouse), i have the error i put in the image that s my problem

Comment: Is your sink a table? If so, what is the schema of the table

Comment: my table has the schema tha but when i unlock the option of tempoDB, it required a schema for create and delete tables, i give the dbo schema for adf

Comment: Why not use the tempDB option?

Comment: because it s throw me a error for the size of my csv, tempoDB can t be use with big tables(my csv has 4000000 rows)

Comment: So the problem now is specifying a schema for your table?

Comment: i give the dbo schema, i don t know if it s the problem. I don t know the cause of the error 
:
Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': 111212;Operation cannot be performed within a transaction.